# model binder provider not being called in dotnet core 1.1.1, mvc 1.1.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have created a brand new .netcore project using the wizard, and added the following.

**The Model Binder Provider is Never Called**

Is this a bug? What am I missing? If I just throw an exception in `GetBinder` it's never reached.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(
        _ =>
        {
            _.ModelBinderProviders.Add(new PartyModelBinderProvider());
        });
}
```

The provider

```
public class PartyModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Party))
            return new PartyModelBinder();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The binder

```
public class PartyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

My action methods are pretty simple.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View(new Party());
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(Party party)
{
    return View(party);
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `AddMvc` method with a parameter not named as `_`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the `Add` method doesn't achieve the desired result, as the model binders are evaluated in order, until one is selected.

The only way to add a model binder in *dotnet core* is to use `Insert`.

```
services.AddMvc(
    _ =>
    {
        _.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new PartyModelBinderProvider());
    });
```